# Create iZettle product via api (Guzzle php)

Tags: java, php, api, guzzle

I'm trying to create a product via the product library from iZettle (https://products.izettle.com/swagger#operation/create-product)

The code:

```
$response = self::$client->request('POST', 'https://products.izettle.com/organizations/self/products', [
                'headers' => self::$headers,
                'json' => [
                    'uuid' => $this->generateUuid()->string,
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'description' => $data['description'],
                    'variants' => [
                        [
                            'uuid' => $this->generateUuid()->string,
                            'name' => 'default',
                            'options' => [
                                'name' => 'default',
                                'value' => 'default'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
```

The headers:

```
self::$headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . Auth::user()->izettle_access_token,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ];
```

The `$client` is a guzzle php client.

When i do this i get the following response:

[image: api error]

Does someone know how i can fix this?

Comment: use try catch to catch the ClientException, then use` $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();` to get your complete error message, right now it is truncated. Also I don't know why but your question is posted 5 days ago but I only saw today

Comment: Thanks for the response man! I think i found the issue. 'options' in 'variants' expects a array. So: ```'options' => [ ['name' => <name>], [--] ]```